# How can I change the default product images sizes on Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, configuration, product-images, magento-2.0, gallery-image

In **magento 1.x.x**, we could change default thumbnail images in admin :

**System > Configuration > Catalog**

But in **magento 2.0**, how can I change theses value I can not seem to find any configs to allow this? The problem is that my product images are displaying with large white stripes and I would like to prevent this.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Magento uses the file called `view.xml` which is maintained at the theme level of the application.

So for example, if you are using the default theme `luma` you should find the `view.xml` under `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml`

In this file, you would see `<images/>` node inside the `<media>` node.

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="bundled_product_customization_page" type="thumbnail">
                <width>140</width>
                <height>140</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_cross_sell_products" type="thumbnail">
                <width>200</width>
                <height>248</height>
            </image>
            <image id="cart_page_product_thumbnail" type="small_image">
                <width>165</width>
                <height>165</height>
            </image>
            ........
        </images>
    </media>
    ......
</view>
```

The dimension of the images is maintained here under the `<image/>` node.

The `id` attribute value of the `<image/>` node is referenced in the codebase.

For example:

```
<image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
    <width>152</width>
    <height>190</height>
</image>
```

The id value is used in the view file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`

```
case 'related':
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related $block */
    if ($exist = $block->getItems()->getSize()) {
        $type = 'related';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'related_products_list';
        $title = __('Related Products');
        $items = $block->getItems();
        $limit = 0;
        $shuffle = 0;
        $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

        $showWishlist = true;
        $showCompare = true;
        $showCart = false;
        $templateType = null;
        $description = false;
    }
break;
```

Here the `$image` refers to the value of the image size here:

```
<?php echo $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml(); ?>
```

In case the theme does not have a `view.xml`, then it might be using a fallback theme (parent theme) which has the `view.xml` file.

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Magento Luma</title>
    <parent>Magento/blank</parent>
    .....
</theme>
```

Here `Magento/blank` is the parent theme.

In case of changing/overwriting the values of the `view.xml` file you need to completely copy the entire `view.xml` file to your custom theme and change the values.

> `view.xml` does not have a node value fallback system, means if a value of a node is not present in you custom theme's `view.xml` **it will not** fallback to its parent theme's view.xml value, that's why entire file needs to be copied.

Once the values changes have been done, you will have to run

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

**Update:** As of Magento 2.4 this command supports synchronous (default) and asynchronous modes. Asynchronous means that images will not be processed immediately on command execution. Using the Magento queue functionality, these images will be scheduled for resizing and then processed in the background. To enable asynchronous mode, use the -a or --async option.

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize -a
```

To speed up the job while in asynchronous mode, you may manually run several instances of a consumer with the command in each instance:

```
php bin/magento queue:consumer:start media.storage.catalog.image.resize
```

> - [Magento 2 frontend architecture](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/frontend-theme-architecture/)
> - [Creating Custom Theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)
> - [Image resize properties](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html)

Comment: Thanks. I'd have never figured where this was being generated. +1

Comment: Got to love how over engineered this is and yet lacking in documentation.
You'd have to look into code or dig around db schema just to figure out these names.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I tired and found the Last setup run `php bin/magento catalog:images:resize` **doesn't need(it costs a lot of time)**, we just need clear the cache and then it will work.

Comment: @KeyShang you are correct, the resized images get generated in runtime if not present already. It is however recommended you run this command as it helps with performance on production

Comment: @MiguelFelipeGuillenCalo I know right!! Also the default view.xml causes 20+ versions of each image...! Some basically identical! Goodness me I hate Magento so much...

Comment: And there is no easy way to set high res @2x images, many of the image sizes are tied to the frontend layout, so they display at the exact size you set them. And the css to change this is so convoluted, full of flakey dependant maths and magic numbers. (look at the cart styling): Disgusting :/

Answer (score 6):

Magento product uses the file ***view.xml*** for image size dimensions at path ***vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml***

Here you will find  node inside the  node.

Copy the file view.xml and put it in your theme path and make the changes, say ***app/design/frontend/MyThemePackage/MyTheme/etc/view.xml***

```
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
<media>
    <images module="Magento_Catalog">
        ........
        <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
             <width>270</width>
             <height>450</height>
        </image>
        ........
    </images>
</media>
......
</view>
```

Clear the cache and load the category list page. Your changes will be reflected.

Comment: It is note worthy that extend path "vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml" can also be "vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/etc/view.xml" depending on which default theme package you use.

Comment: how to change the thumbnail image size in product detail page?

Answer (score 2):

You can also specify image dimensions directly in template file like this:

```
<?php
/**
* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget
*/
$image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
$items = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems();
$width = 100;
$height = 100;
foreach ($items as $_item) {
    $resizedUrl = $block->resizeImage($_item, $image , $width, $height)->getUrl();
    echo '<img src="'.$resizedUrl .'" alt="alt text" />';
}
```