# Change the size of the swatch image

Tags: image, thumbnail

I'm looking to change the size of the default swatch thumb in the layered navigation.

I've tried changing the view.xml from the theme and running:

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

The command is successful but no image sizes change.

[This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122569/magento-2-change-default-product-images-sizes) is the main post I've looked at.

In view.xml I have:

```
    <image id="swatch_image" type="swatch_image">
         <width>120</width>
         <height>90</height>
    </image>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you changed the values for swatch size but inside your view.xml file following needs adding:

```
<image id="swatch_image" type="swatch_image">
             <width>50</width>
             <height>50</height>
</image>
```

Adjust height and run `php bin/magento catalog:images:resize`

Comment: Thanks Devtype, yes, I've added code like that but there's been no change after running the command successfully.

Answer (score 0):

1. change view.xml
2. refresh magento's cache
3. run php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
4. flush browser's cache
5. check the css which wraps the swatch images

Answer (score 0):

Anyone known how to show "thumbnail" instead of "swatch image"?