# Set product image size?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, theme, product-images

I got this method in my RelatedProduct class that gets related product image URL

```
public function getProductImageUrl($product)
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()
                ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
}
```

and when I use it in my template

```
<img src=" <?= $product->getProductImageUrl($relatedProduct) ?> ">
```

the image is too large, it takes up whole screen.

How can I set the size of the image to base image size, preferably without having to add css styling for it? Can I do it in some .xml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have the full answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122570/33619
You have to use the `view.xml` file in your theme to set your different sizes and them call them in your template by their code.

In your `view.xml`

```
<image id="your_image_id" type="small_image">
    <width>152</width>
    <height>190</height>
</image>
```

In your template

```
<?php echo $block->getImage($product, 'your_image_id')->toHtml(); ?>
```