# How to increase related products slider image size?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am using Ultimo theme. Does anyone know how to increase the related products slider image size on the product page in magento 2?

Comment: please update your related product slider code.

Comment: There is no code for this slider. This slider is part of the theme settings.

Comment: please check the phtml file or widget code to call the related product slider.

Comment: @haya have you checked the Ultimo theme magento user guide

Comment: @Haya Please share your related slider code, so I will guide you how to update height width.

Comment: use custom css (it's not recommended but it's the most easiest way to do what you want)

Answer (score 3):

You can change product image size from here:

> app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/etc/view.xml

As per default Magento You can edit following code to change image size for Related Products in your **view.xml**

```
<image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
      <width>340</width>
      <height>450</height>
</image>
```

Find image id which is used for Related Products image.

Please don't forget to clear cache after change.

Comment: How can I find the image ID? I already changed the size for image ID related_products_list in view.xml. But I don't see any changes in the frontend?

Comment: try to change width and height in image id = items_grid_thumbnails_s.

Comment: I just changed items_grid_thumbnails_s and related_products_list. There seems to be no effect on the frontend

Comment: you can echo $imageTypeId before your image tag in your template to find image id or you can create new image id and use that in your template.

Comment: Dimension of existing image size in frontend is 140 x 193. So I went ahead and changed all instances of that in view.xml to 183 x 252. But still nothing changes in the frontend. Any clue? I have disabled the cache and it is developer mode. Removed temp files. Did everything possible.

Comment: create new image id and use that image for related case in your template. <?php echo $helperImage->getImageUrl($_item,'new_image_id', $imgWidth, $imgHeight); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to view.xml file of your theme.

```
<image id="related_products_list" type="small_image">
    <width>340</width>
    <height>450</height>
</image>
```

And run below command from terminal:

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Comment: I already did that. And ran resize command that took almost like 1 hour. Cleared cache. But no change in the frontend.

Comment: can you let us know how are you calling the images? Check the image dimension.

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158251/set-product-image-size?rq=1