# How can I add an image to view in in magento2?

Tags: magento2, template, external-images

... in my phtml view

I want to add a image in my view.

Somebody know how to do it ?

Thanks for help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 > Change default product images sizes](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122569/magento-2-change-default-product-images-sizes)

Comment: @MatthéoGeoffray Duplicate of product images? The word 'product' is nowhere used in this question... Please be accurate in flagging as duplicate

Comment: Yes the `phtml view`  misslead me I thought it was for product images. My bad.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I hope you ask how to show image in phtml

**If you call image from theme**

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('img/image.jpg'); ?>" />
```

image location should be

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/web/img/image.jpg

---

**If you call image from module**

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::img/image.jpg'); ?>" />
```

image location should be

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/img/image.jpg

Comment: yup that is the default path for static file like js,css,image. If you set developer mode it will generate automatically from module and theme by symlink. If you felt any issue in static file generation follow this answer http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/94506/36463