# try to change all base images to bigger size images by importing the CSV file, but failed

Tags: magento2, import, image, file, cvs

I used the small size image as the base image before.  Now I tried to change all the base images from 250x250 to 800x800 by import the product CSV file. After successfully importing, the small base images are not replaced by bigger images, still remain the same.

Please help!!

Comment: Please follow this answer for same https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122569/how-can-i-change-the-default-product-images-sizes-on-magento-2

Comment: I imported the bigger size image files by specifying them  to the 'base image' column of the CVS file.  But the admin import script does not change the base image to the bigger file after successful importing. This has to do with the import script. and has nothing to do with the url you mentioned.

Comment: If I manually drag one big image to the product 'image or video' menu from the backend.  It will show the big product image at the frontend.  But it only works one product at a time. I have about 5000 products, I can not do it by this way.