# Magento Product Images in Cache

Tags: product-images, cache, magento2.2.3

When I check /pub/media/catalog/product/cache/, there are many folders. Each folder contains the same images with different size. So I'm not sure about why there are same images with different size.

Answer (score 0):

refer to this [Images sizes in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122569/how-can-i-change-the-default-product-images-sizes-on-magento-2)

You have a different size depending on the number of format defined for this image in your template...